# UITextView's boundingRect Not Working Properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently have the following extension on UITextField to calculate the bounding rect for a given string.

```
func widthHeight(font: UIFont) -> CGRect {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: 200, height: 1000)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
    return boundingBox
}
```

The width for `constraintRect` is the maximum width I want to allow for the box.

I set the values and the cells like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuse, for: indexPath) as? ChatCollectionViewCell {

        let text = self.chatLog[indexPath.row].text
        cell.chatTextView.text = text

        cell.chatViewWidth = (text?.widthHeight(font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)).width)!

        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if let text = self.chatLog[indexPath.row].text {            
        let box = text.widthHeight(font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16))
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: box.height + 10)
    }
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 60)
}
```

When this code runs, I get massively miscalculated cell sizes:
[image]

As you can see, the view's frames are very messed up.
The first line is "Heya", the second line is "How's life going so far", and the third line is "I'm a stapler, you're a textbook." Some cells are too narrow, some cells are too wide.

Here's some additional code for my custom collectionViewCell:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {

    chatView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: chatViewWidth, height: frame.height)
    chatTextView.frame = CGRect(x: chatView.frame.origin.x + 10, y: 0, width: chatView.frame.width - 20, height: chatView.frame.height)
}

func setupViews() {    

    if isTextFromCurrentUser {
        chatTextView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: frame.width - 140, height: frame.height)
        chatTextView.backgroundColor = .white
    } else {
        chatTextView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width - 150, y: 0, width: frame.width - 140, height: frame.height)
        chatTextView.backgroundColor = .blue
    }

    chatTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    chatTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 9
    chatTextView.clipsToBounds = true
    chatTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
    chatTextView.isScrollEnabled = false

    contentView.addSubview(chatView)
    contentView.addSubview(chatTextView)
}
```

Comment: `widthHeight(...)` is certainly an odd name for a method that essentially returns a **size**... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chemo,

As I believe its a chat bubble to which you are trying to set the hight for and chat bubble cant have any scroll inside it make sure your textView's scroll is disabled.

Second as Chat bubble should increase its height based on content and there is no height limit use `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` as possible height that you can accommodate while calculating boundingRect

```
func widthHeight(font: UIFont) -> CGRect {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: 200, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
    return boundingBox
}
```

Finally make sure there is no `contentInset` set to the textView. If `contentInset` set as left 5 and right 5 make sure to subtract 10 (5 + 5) from max width you can accommodate.

As height is the only variable here in equation setting width exactly is the key to get correct height. Make sure you set the line options correct matching ur textViews property.

**Suggestion:**

`UITableView` can make use of automatic height for cell and setting scroll disable on textView makes textView to calculate its size based on the text set. I mean textView will respect the implicit size.

As I believe you are creating a chat app where each bubble is a cell, consider more sane option of using UITableView and leverage the benefit of automatic cell height then messing up with collectionView which expects you to provide the size for each item manually.

**Pinch of Advice :D**

I have personally used bounding rect and managed to calculate the exact height for text after loads of trial and error method. I personally suggest creating a textView instance, setting its property exactly matching the property of textView you have in your storyboard and then set the text you wanna show and use sizeThatFits to get the actual size of textView which is much easier.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)
       //set textView property here 
       textView.text = self.chatLog[indexPath.row].text
       let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
       return size;
}
```

Comment: Yesss thank you! I ended up changing to using NSLayoutConstraints which made things clearer, and uiedgeinsets were definitely screwing things up.

Comment: @chemo : am glad you solved the issue buddy :) Happy coding and always welcome

Comment: @SandeepBhandari thanks, I've been around this for quite a time!